# Messed up Mesh on Object

Tags: modeling, mesh, normals

I was trying to bevel the edges of a cylinder, and then I got all this mess showing up within the faces of my object. I tried to recalculate normals but its not clearing up.

Thank you.

[image]

Comment: it's very hard to understand your screenshot, maybe share your file? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Answer (score 0):

you got double faces.

in edit mode select all verts.
alt + M > By distance > if the double faces are not gone hit f9 in 3d view and make the distance more.